# High School lit text from the 60s or 70s. One story had an Osmosis Jones type of hero

Tags: story-identification

Story was about the quest of a creature who used a straw to draw nutrition from the bio mass he was traveling through. That's all I remember. I read it in 1970 or 1971. In one of our anthology lit texts. He was scrappy. I read someone else talk about *Pail of Air*, Leiber's story. It may have included that story and perhaps a story about the plague where a guy has to pass through a room where large blue bottle flies try to wriggle past his lips while his hands are occupied and he can't slap them off his face.